# array index difference notation Python <-> R

Tags: r

what is the Python notation `a[i-j]` translated to R? As far as I understand it, it should be the array element at position i-j. But in R it seems to be the array until the ith element subtracted by the element at position j.

Comment: Could you give a simple (executable) example? I can't seem to repeat.

Comment: Use commas to separate dimensions: `a[i, j]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R and Python have somewhat similar indexing properties, with the main difference being that indexing in Python starts at 0 while in R it starts at 1. Beyond the index start, there is also the fact that Python supports negative indexing, while in R negative indexing means that you are removing the element at that exact index from your list. To be specific to your case, the indexing `list[i-j]` could be ***somewhat*** the same thing if `i - j` returns a positive integer. Otherwise, you are talking about two completely different things. The illustration below should be helpful to you:

## Python:

```
#Create a list
lst = [1,3,5,6,7,7]
#index element at 4-2 (which is 2)
lst[4-2] # returns 5
#index element at 2-4 (which is -2) or lst[len(lst)-2]
lst[2-4] # returns 7
```

## R:

```
lst <- c(1,3,5,6,7,7)

#indexing element at 4-2 (which is 2)

lst[4-2] # returns 3 (because R indexing starts at 1, not 0)
[1] 3

#BUT indexing element at 2-4 (which is -2) does not work,
#because it means that you are removing the element at index 2, i.e. 3

lst[2-4] #returns the original list without element at index 2
[1] 1 5 6 7 7
```

These are the main differences in indexing a `list` that I could offer to help with your question. The differences in indexing become more prominent as you tackle more complicated data structures in both languages.

I hope this is helpful.